# Silverlight trusted apps without install certificate in trusted puplishers

Tags: silverlight, trusted

I write SL5 application. I signed with thawte code sign certificate. I set registery that allow run inside browser. 
When I check haselevationpermission I got false. If I install certificate in trusted puplishers I got true.

But my application will be used by enduser and I can't tell them "install this certificate into Trusted publishers"

What is wrong? 
Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to tell them to install into Trusted publishers, as the root certificate should already be there for Thawte.  Try installing on a different machine and see if you get the same results.

When installing OOB with a valid cert, the install dialogs will look different than with an invalid cert.  Does it look like a valid cert, or not when you install?  It should of course.

Also, make sure you check the "Require elevated trust when running outside the browser" checkbox in the OOB settings.

Greg

Answer (score 0):

I tested it on 3 different machine (win 7 , Window server 2008 and windows 8)
In certificate Manager, Trusted publisher list is empty. 
When I install OOB, Cert seems valid. (It shows Company Name as well) 
I also check Require elevated trust when running outside the browser and in browser.